# ¿Porque mi <td> y mi <th> no se encuentra alineados?

Tags: html, css, table

Estoy teniendo problemas al colocar una tabla de manera responsiva, estoy ayudándome con la siguiente `media-queries` para ajustar la tabla:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 425px) {       
        table, thead, tbody, th, td, tr {
            display: block;
        }

        

        tr {
        margin: 0 0 1rem 0;
        }

        #cuerpo{
            display: flex;
        }
        
        div#dias_disfrutar{
            margin: 5px;
            padding: 5px;
            border: 1px solid #4CAF50;
            border-radius: 5px;    
            text-align: center;
            
        }
        
        td {
            /* Behave  like a "row" */
            border: none;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
            position: relative;
            /*padding-left: 50%;*/
        }

        .saldosAnticipados{
            display: flex;
            /*width: 400px;*/
            margin: 3px;
            border: 1px solid #8c8e8c;
            border-radius: 5px;    
        }

        .saldos{
            display: flex;
            width: 400px;
            margin: 1px;
            margin-right: auto;
            border: 1px solid #8c8e8c;
            border-radius: 5px;    
        }

        #div_fechas_seleccionadas{
            width: 160px;
            text-align: center;
            margin: 5px;
            /*padding: 5px;*/
            border: 1px solid cadetblue;
            border-radius: 5px;
            background-color: #CEECF5;    
        }
        
}
```

La tabla se visualiza de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código HTML que estoy usando para crear la tabla es el siguiente:

```
<h3 class="subtitulo">SALDOS</h3>
<div class="saldos">
  <table class="table">
  <thead> 
                        <tr>
                            <th></th>
                            <th>Año</th>
                            <th>Saldo</th>                            
                            <th>Fecha vencimiento</th>
                            <th>Total</th>                            
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><span id="eliminar-saldo-btn" title="Eliminar">x</span></td>
                        <td data-title="Año"></td>
                        <td data-title="Saldo"></td>
                        <td data-title="Saldo">0</td>
                        <td data-title="Fecha vencimiento"></td>
                        </tr>            
                        </tbody>         
  </table>
</div>
```

Lo que deseo es que los valores corresponda con los datos de la tabla de una manera alineada.

**Actualización:**

Originalmente mi tabla en una vista no responsiva se ve de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Actualización 2:**

Realizando otras modificaciones en mi CSS he obtenido hasta ahora lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el cambio que hice en mi `media-query`

```
table#cuerpo, thead#cuerpo, tbody#cuerpo, th#cuerpo, td, tr#cuerpo {
            display: block;
            
        }
```

Comment: Yo no termino de entender cual es el problema, ¿puedes explicar mejor?

Comment: @BetaM La tabla que esta en la imagen de arriba es como se ve de manera Responsiva, la tabla de abajo es como se ve de manera No Responsiva, como puedo hacer para que mi tabla no pierda su forma al pasarlo a forma responsiva ? Si lo paso de manera responsiva su celdas no se alinean